# Move point A to point B in a arc motion in 3D

Tags: python, math, 3d

I'm struggling to work out how I move point A to B in an arc motion in 3D. The duration of the movement doesn't matter so much. I have found a load of wikipedia pages on it but am having no luck understanding them as its been a long time since I was in college. Any code examples would be really useful for me to understand. Thank you, I would really appreciate your help. Here is an image that sort of shows what I am looking to achieve, although the image only represents the points in 2d, I am looking for a 3d solution.

[image: illustration]

Comment: By "arc", do you mean exact semicircle? In 2D, there are two ways of doing this between any point. In 3D, there are infinitely many - which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem statement is:

> Given points `a` and `b`, trace the circular path along the plane which lies tangent to the `up` vector:

And that you have the appropriate vector algebra libraries:

```
def interp(a, b, up, t):
    """ 0 <= t <= 1"""

    # find center and radius vector
    center = (a + b) / 2
    radius = a - center

    # split path into upwards and downwards section
    omega = math.acos(radius.dot(up))  # angle between center-a and center-top
    t_top = omega / math.pi  # time taken to reach the top

    # redefine 0 as A, 1 as the top, and B as whatever remains linear
    t = t / t_top

    #slerp, with t intentionally > 1
    sin = math.sin
    return (
        center +
        sin((1 - t) * omega) / sin(omega) * radius +
        sin(t * omega) / sin(omega) * up
    )
```

Comment: It would be nice to explicitly state the library dependencies. Also, I would use a vector orthogonal to the desired plane together with the cross-product and left- or right-hand rule instead of `up` - but the OP did not specify this anyway...

Comment: @mbschenkel: I'm not specifying a dependancy, because there's no one that you'd need here. `numpy` is one choice, `pyeuclid` is another. Isn't the desired plane best identified with the `up` vector anyway? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with python, so thanks for the pointers. There's an infinite number of "`up`-vectors", while the (unit-)vector `v` orthogonal to the plane is unique (actually there are of course two: `v` and `-v`, but this ambiguity can be used to define the direction of rotation.) An `up` vector can then easily be calculated as `up = v x (a-b)` where `x` is the cross-product.

Comment: _"the plane"_ - which plane? There's no `v` we can pick to guarantee that all `a`, `b` lie on the plane with that normal. We can pick any `up` vector though, and guarantee that a plane with that tangent passes through `a` and `b`. The OP's diagram is unclear as to how it extends to 3D - I'm looking at it as a vertical slice through the world

Comment: The 'vertical slice through the world' is a plane, isn't it? But you are right about the required orthogonality, your approach is thus more general and should be preferred...

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt matter if its 2d or 3d . 
you take the position of each dot and find the center beetwean them . 
the distance beetwean the center and each dot is the radius . 
after that give the object a moving direction and tell it to be always in a distance of radius from center .  which a moving vector you can give it any direction you want .